# How to maximize an objective function with a max operator in the function

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

My optimization problem looks like this:
$$
\underset{\boldsymbol{x}}{\max}\quad f\left( \boldsymbol{x} \right) +\underset{y\in Y}{\max}g\left( \boldsymbol{x},y \right) \\
\mathrm{s.t.} 0\le x_i \le x_{max}, \forall x_i \in \boldsymbol{x}
$$
where $\boldsymbol{x}\in\mathbb{C}^{N\times1}$ is a vector and $y$ is an integer. $f(\boldsymbol{x})$ is concave with respect to $\boldsymbol{x}$, and $g\left( \boldsymbol{x},y \right)$ is concave with respect to $\boldsymbol{x}$ with given $y$.

By applying alternating optimization (AO) method, I can get the optimal $y^{\star}$ with given $\boldsymbol{\tilde{x}}\in X$ and get the optimal $\boldsymbol{x}^{\star}$ with given $\tilde{y}\in Y$. I want to solve this optimization problem without using AO method to get a better performance, but it is difficult for me to deal with the term $\underset{y\in Y}{\max}g\left( \boldsymbol{x},y \right) $. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Just maximize $f(x)+g(x,y)$ subject to
\begin{align}
0 \le x_i &\le x_\max &&\text{for all $i$} \\
y &\in Y
\end{align}

Comment: I have tried similar methods and only got numerical results. But I want to get a closed-form solution of the primal problem. Is there any other way? Thanks a lot.